# Google Sheets Pivot data with multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to get my set of data to be pivot without using pivot table

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0BLJ.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HDtB.png)

Comment: What is the issue you have met?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: I have attached here with the sample sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ox2cL1JvjoF4Hkoxj-xsTB_vQr3oWNeKv5RhyS4rBo8/edit?pli=1#gid=0 I'm trying to figure out a single formula to get Data A to Data Result. I've tried query pivot formula but I can't get it to work. I've also tried using player0's formula but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Added Solution to your [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ox2cL1JvjoF4Hkoxj-xsTB_vQr3oWNeKv5RhyS4rBo8/edit?pli=1#gid=1848563970)

formula in cell K13:

`={ArrayFormula(IF(COUNTIFS({QUERY({{C2,B2};SORT({C3:C7,B3:B7},1,1,2,1)},"Select Col1")},{QUERY({{C2,B2};SORT({C3:C7,B3:B7},1,1,2,1)},"Select Col1")},ROW(A2:A7),"<="&ROW(A2:A7))>1,,{QUERY({{C2,B2};SORT({C3:C7,B3:B7},1,1,2,1)},"Select Col1")})),QUERY(SORT({{C2:C7},{B2:B7},{"Q4 2022";BYROW(filter(D3:I7,REGEXMATCH(to_TEXT(MONTH(D2:I2)),"^10$|^11$|^12$")),LAMBDA(ax,sum(ax)))},{"Q1 2023";BYROW(filter(D3:I7,REGEXMATCH(to_TEXT(MONTH(D2:I2)),"^1$|^2$|^3$")),LAMBDA(ax,sum(ax)))}},1,1,2,1),"Select Col2, Col3, Col4")}`

-
[image]